# How can I use a computer to control a wired / wireless PWM controller to control the speed of a dc motor

Tags: hardware, power

How can I use a computer to control a wired / wireless PWM controller to control the speed of a dc motor (I will be testing both wired and wireless to test response)

I have a **DC motor 6-12**v mini [DC motor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M58POHF) (**I also will be trying small brushless motors**) that I would like to control it's speed using a computer / raspberry pi

[image: DC motor image]

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B01M58POHF/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M58POHF)

**My Use Example**: Have the computer increase the speed in increments by 0.2 volts / pulses over a span of time until it reaches 11.6 volts and record the time and it's voltage when it's reached.

How can I go about this? What hardware do I need to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: L298N controller https://www.amazon.com/Qunqi-Controller-Module-Stepper-Arduino/dp/B014KMHSW6

Comment: how you do it depends on if you will be doing it wired or wireless ... or do you mean both wired and wireless?

Comment: @JaromandaX I'm going to be testing both wired and wireless (want to see the response)